# Using external modules in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Lets say we have the following 2 external modules in TypeScript:

```
export module My.Services.Common 
{
    export class Helper 
    {
       //...
    }
}
```

and

```
export module My.Services 
{
    export class Connection
    {
        //...
    }    
}
```

Now in my app.ts I would like to use both Connection and Helper classes.
What I want to achieve is similar to the following code in C#:

```
using My.Services;
using My.Services.Common;
```

Or at least just

```
using My.Services;
```

But it looks like I cant work at the same time with both Helper and Connection. If I write:

```
import {My} from './services/common/Helper';
import {My} from './services/Connection;
```

Leads to error "duplicate identifier 'My'". That is logical though.
So my question is how can I consume different classes from the same (or nested) modules?

Comment: See my answer. It might be what you are wanting to accomplish!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My personal view on this is to break away from what you see in C# or Java (which maps more closely to *internal* modules) and treat it more like the external modules you are using...

Step 1. Ditch the `module` keyword. The file is a module already.

Step 2. Provide a non-dotted alias when you import.

Step 3. You can now import everything, '*', or specific classes when you import.

*./services/common.ts*

```
export class Helper 
{
   //...
}
```

*./services.ts*

```
export class Connection
{
    //...
}
```

*./app.ts*

```
import * as Services from './services'
import { Connection } from './services/common'

var x = new Services.Helper();

var y = new Connection();
```

You can import multiple members from a module too:

```
import { Connection, Example } from './services/common'

var y = new Connection();

var z = new Example();
```

Comment: but how can one place Connection in the same namespace as Services? As in, what if I want one-class-per-file? I need to aggregate these various classes in some way to show they are in the same module.

Comment: @Jefftopia the file is the module, the folder structure provides namespaces. For example, you might use the files `list.ts` for a list module and `dictionary.ts` for a dictionary module, and place them in: './system/collections/generic/list' and './system/collections/generic/dictionary' respectively.

Comment: But that doesn't scale. At scale, you don't want one file for one module. You might want one file per class, which is the standard approach.

Comment: @Jefftopia "one file per class" is a standard approach in C#, but not JavaScript. In JavaScript one module per file is a standard approach - so beware of widening the definition of "standard". You'll also have to substantiate the claim that it doesn't scale - I can't respond to it without making assumptions about what you intended by that statement.

Comment: @Fenton Why is one module per file standard in javascript? Because it has to be due to how modules are implemented, or because it's better? I feel like Jefftopia here, having to put everything I want in a container/module into the same file does not scale and worsens the cognitive load having to work like this. There is a reason why other languages has one class/interface/struct/etc. per file, and it's not because of language semantics.

Comment: @Alex it is a standard in JavaScript because the definition of a module is a file. You can still organise your modules to aid maintainability and you _could_ limit a module to a single class, or a single function, or a single constant (whatever you want). You don't _have_ to have any classes in your JavaScript program and you don't even have to use the object-oriented paradigm. It is wonderfully open.

Comment: @Fenton `it is a standard in JavaScript because the definition of a module is a file` But that's a tautology. And I don't get why you offer me the possibility not to use classes and object orientation, how does that help me with the ability to bundle the components in my system into a discoverable namespace when using external modules?

Comment: @Alex instead of creating in-code namespaces, you use the file system to organise the code into virtual namespaces. The path to the file is a natural namespace, each file is a module, and the contents of the module is whatever you want.

Comment: @Fenton But that won't give you explorative intellisense. You can't write `var foo = Models/DTO/Accounting/..` and have your IDE help you get what you want. You can't do a quick check if that function you know is somewhere but don't remember the name of is in Data.Transport.Util or Transformations.Transport. This decreases the efficiency in navigating your codebase, which I consider hugely important. I want my single-file-per-unit policy and my namespaces, and I think Varuns answer here below together with some automation is the solution.

Comment: @Alex I don't know what IDE you are using, but Visual Studio code has auto imports, so you just type the class name and it will suggest the import for you. That's just a tooling issue.

Comment: @Fenton But then you have to adress the specific class, which mean that you will lose the organisational explorability provided by namespaces. Instead you have to rely on the folder structure on disk for your cognitive navigation. I don't want to switch over to exploring the file system when I'm used to proper language semantics to navigate my codebase.

Comment: @Alex I don't understand your concern. An IDE can auto-complete a dot syntax: `My.Namespace.[suggest]` and an IDE can auto-complete an import statement: `./My/Namespace/[suggest]`. It can also automatically add the import statement if I use the class name. You seem to be arguing with me about decisions made by TC39? https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-modules

Comment: @Fenton I'm continuing on Jefftopias statement that it does not scale, for which you requested clarification. What don't scale is the ability to explore the code structure using proper language semantics with efficient tooling. Exploring through import statements is not equivalent: You can't do `var data = ./My/Namespace/Util/...` like you can with namespaces, and import statements have a lot of extra semantics compared to walking down namespaces: `import * as Donno from ":/..."`, if you would try to use import statements exploratively in the first place.

Comment: Not having merging namespaces also leads to that you either have to put a lot of stuff in your organisational containers (files) which increase clutter and reduce cognitive separation of concerns, OR that you have to depend on a explicitly linking every dependency to each other, which takes more work and effort.

This is why it does not scale organizationally. You either get bloaty contexts, or more overhead. Internal modules/namespaces (in typescript) are much easier to work with, but the tooling/infrastructure is unfortunately underdeveloped due to external modules being the "right path".

Answer (score 12):

To add to Steve's good answer, since I've already drawn the ASCII art: The top-level object exported from this module, `My`, doesn't merge with any other object from other files named `My`. The only thing the `My.Services.Common` module achieves is making it more annoying to import `Helper`, because you have to fully qualify its name *even though there's nothing else in there*.

What you think you've done:

```
/-My--------------------\
| /-Services---------\  |
| | /-Common---\     |  |
| | | [Helper] |     |  |
| | \----------/     |  |
| |                  |  |
| | [Connection]     |  |
| \------------------/  |
\-----------------------/
```

What you've actually done:

```
/-My---------------\   /-My---------------\ 
| /-Services-----\ |   | /-Services-----\ |
| | /-Common---\ | |   | | [Connection] | |
| | | [Helper] | | |   | \--------------/ |
| | \----------/ | |   \------------------/
| \--------------/ | 
\------------------/
```

This is like having an organization system in your house where you have a dozen shoeboxes, *each* with a single smaller box inside it, each with a smaller box inside that one. The nested boxes provide no organizational benefit over the shoeboxes!

Comment: Extra points for all that ASCII art. You even did rounded corners!

Comment: I don't even understand the point of `module`. Everywhere I read, people are like saying not to use it. Even worse with the `namespace` which pollutes the global namespace. I feel like I should just forget those two and only use classes and interfaces without any kind of encapsulation.

Comment: `namespace` doesn't necessarily pollute the global namespace. If you're creating a large-ish ES6 module, you might still use `namesapce` to organize the objects inside it

Answer (score 2):

I have found another approach for tackling this organisation problem.

To go back to ASCII art (ᵔᴥᵔ)

My folder structure is so:

```
|
|-- myawesomemodule
|         |
|         |-- myawesomeclass.ts
|         |-- myevenmoreawesomeclass.ts
|         |-- myawesomemodule.ts
|
|-- myevenmoreawesomemodule
|         |-- myotherclass.ts
|         |-- myanotherclass.ts
|         |-- myevenmoreawesomemodule.ts
|
index.ts
```

In `myawesomemodule.ts`, I do:

```
export {MyAwesomeClass} from './myawesomeclass'
export {MyEvenMoreAwesomeClass} from './myevenmoreawesomeclass'
```

Similarly in `myevenmoreawesomemodule.ts`, I do:

```
export {MyOtherClass} from './myotherclass'
export {MyAnotherClass} from './myanotherclass'
```

And finally at the root level in `index.ts`, I do:

```
import * as MyAwesomeModule from "./myawesomemodule/myawesomemodule";
import * as MyEvenMoreAwesomeModule from "./myevenmoreawesomemodule/myevenmoreawesomemodule";

export {MyAwesomeModule};
export {MyEvenMoreAwesomeModule};
```

Now I can ship this module off to a consumer, pack as NPM etc.

From a consumer, I do:

```
import MyPackage = require("mypackage"); //assuming you did npm pack
```

OR

```
import * as MyPackage from "./path/to/index" //assuming you didn't
```

Then I refer to my class names so:

```
let instance = new MyPackage.MyAwesomeModule.MyAwesomeClass();
```

I find this approach a bit better than exposing all my classes in a big module at the root level.

Comment: Thank you very much for this post! I'm also writing an API in TS and couldn't figure out how to export classes the consumer will need without forcing him to load lots of different modules.

Comment: I think I like this, and I currently trying if this is a good structure for a project growing to far... One question: I think in all filenames (red writing) you need to remove the .ts?