# How can i write module & classes across typescript files

Tags: typescript

I am trying to structure an app using typescript and angular. I have followed various example which point to the use of modules to group certain aspects together, however not sure if what i am getting is going to work...

I have one file called test.ts with the following structure

```
module test
{
  class Blah
  {

  }

}
```

The second file test2.ts is as follows

```
module test
{
   class Blah2
   {

   }

}
```

When TS generates this code in Javascript i am left with a duplicate variable definition for "var test" which doesnt seem right...

```
var test;
(function (test) {
       var Blah = ......
})(test || (test = {}));

var test;
(function (test) {
       var Blah2 = ......
})(test || (test = {}));
```

How can i get around the duplicate variable definition of 'test' or is this not a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Each file is already a module in typescript. You should get away from the C# 'namespace' like thinking about modules in typescript. I had similar issues to the one you do now with background in C#. 
Have a look at this question here:
[using external modules in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30176289/using-external-modules-in-typescript)

I think it will help you to understand.

Comment: Hi - if i remove the module definition i get global namespace pollution because every class becomes a global variable....

Comment: There is not such thing as 'global namespace'. The main thing is that the modular structure of your program is basically defined by its file/folder structure. You group your 'similar' classes in the same folders. And to consume modules you import only classes you need (or all using *) via 'import' statements. And bear in mind that having one class per file is not that bad idea.

Comment: I cannot believe that it would be good practice to remove the module definition and simply have many global variables such as var Blah, var Blah2 .... every single class becomes a variable which doesnt seem right at all. This might be okay for small apps but not for larger ones...

Comment: Of course is bad to write your typescript program with tons of global variables. But we are talking about typescript, not javascript. How typescript is compiled to javascript and the approaches it use to provide you with the concept of modules is its internal implementation depending on the target module 'amd', 'commonjs' etc. It gives you the way to organize your code into modules by the means of file structure (and I think this is the only way to go for larger applications). After all, when you are speaking about namespaces in C# you are not thinking in terms of generated MSIL.

Comment: It is only the case that “each file is already a module” if you are writing your TypeScript files as external modules using the `import` and `export` keywords. Otherwise, TypeScript files are *not* modules.

Comment: @CSnover your comment is actually the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i get around the duplicate variable definition of 'test' or is this not a problem?

It's not a problem because of JavaScript hoisting. A variable is "hoisted" up to where it's first used. It does not get redefined unless you set a new value to it.

The namespace pattern can be written like this:

```
(function (namespace) {
   ...
}(window.namespace = window.namespace || {}));

// or similarly

(function (namespace) {
   ...
}(window.namespace || (window.namespace = {})));
```

In other words: "declare a function and invoke it immediately, passing an object; if the object has not been initialized yet, create a new object from scratch and use that, otherwise continue building off of the same object."

TypeScript is generating basically equivalent code, just without explicitly referring to the window object:

```
var namespace; // same as window.namespace but does not assume window exists or what it is
(function (namespace) {
   ...
}(namespace || (namespace = {})));
```

Actually, it would also allow the generated code to not necessarily live in the global namespace. `var namespace;` is the same as `window.namespace` in the global namespace, but not at some other scope. If your namespace is nested within another namespace, for example, the second namespace uses this same pattern, and the variable is then not implicitly attached to `window`, but lives in the scope of the outer namespace object. Ex:

```
var outerNamespace; // same as window.outerNamespace
(function (outerNamespace) {
   var innerNamespace; // not the same as window.innerNamespace
   (function (innerNamespace) {
      ...
   }(outerNamespace.innerNamespace || (outerNamespace.innerNamespace = {})));
}(outerNamespace || (outerNamespace = {})));

...

var outerNamespace; // doesn't matter because of JS variable hoisting
(function (outerNamespace) {
   ...
}(outerNamespace || (outerNamespace = {})));
```